# как скопировать тест с документа сохраняя форматирование? андроид

Tags: android, textview, android-textview

у меня есть текст в ворд:

[image]

Внутри заголовок и 2 абзаца. Я хочу сохранить их в strings.xml и отобразить в TextView. Но получается каша

:[image]

Как сохранить форматирование?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не советовал сохранение текста в ресурсы. Если вам нужно отобразить содержимое файла, то открывайте его и показывайте в textView. Для открытия файла можно использовать библиотеку [ApachePOI](http://poi.apache.org/text-extraction.html). Данная библиотека в состоянии вытащить данные из файла и отобразить в виджете без использования ресурсов. [Вот](https://javadevblog.com/obzor-biblioteki-apache-poi-rabota-s-prilozheniyami-paketa-microsoft-office-v-java.html) есть обзор библиотеки. Например есть класс `XWPFWordExtractor` который можно использовать [таким](https://www.javatpoint.com/apache-poi-word-extract-text) образом:

```
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Javatpoint.docx")) {  
    XWPFDocument file   = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));  
    XWPFWordExtractor ext = new XWPFWordExtractor(file);  
    System.out.println(ext.getText());  
}catch(Exception e) {  
    System.out.println(e);  
}
```

Еще один вариант - использовать intent для открытия файла, но это будет происходить за пределами приложения:

```
private void openFile(File url) {

    try {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(url);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No application found which can open the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[Вот](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.11) есть страничка библиотеки ApachePOI.